# Can a cell culture insert plate be used with a vacuum manifold?

Tags: cell-culture

There exists 96 well plate setups for use with vacuum manifolds. Is it possible to use 6/12/24 plate inserts with the same setup?

Answer (score 2):

[This company](https://www.unitedchem.com/catalog/sample-prep/manifolds/universal-vacuum-manifold) sells a vacuum manifold for 24, 48 and 96 well plate formats.